# Как убрать срабатывание кода для кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как сделать кнопку без вызова открытия на повторном нажатии?

```js
var opened;
var is_open=false;
$('.block-my_ad').click(function(){
   if(is_open) {
      opened.slideToggle(300);
      is_open=false;
   }
   if(opened != $(this).find('ul')) {
       opened = $(this).find('ul');
       opened.slideToggle(300);
       is_open=true;
   }
});
```

```html
<div class="block-my_ad">
 <p class="my_ad-title" ><strong>'.$row["title"].'</strong></p>
 <p class="my_ad-datetime" >'.$row["datatime"].'</p>
  
  
 <ul>
 <div class="block-images-my_ad">
    <img src="' . $img_path . '" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '">
  </div>
 <li><strong>Категория</strong> - '.$row["category"].'</li>
 <li><strong>Цель</strong> - '. (!empty($row["x"]) ? $row["x"] : (!empty($row["y"]) ? $row["y"] : $row["t"])) . '</li>
 <li><strong>Город</strong> - '.$row["gorod"].'</li>
 <li><strong>Телефон</strong> - '.$row["phone"].'</li>
 <li><strong>Описание</strong> - '.$row["descriptions"].'</li>
 <p class="my_ad-links" ><a class="delete" rel="my_ad.php?id='.$row["products_id"].'&action=delete" >Удалить</a></p>
 </ul>
  </div>
 ';
```

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as Ham to Hamster (c)

Answer (score -2):

```js
var opened;
$('.block-my_ad').click(function(){
 if (!opened) {
  opened = $(this).find('ul');
  opened.slideToggle(300);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='block-my_ad'>Открыть меню
 <ul style='display: none;'>
  <li>Пункт меню 1</li>
  <li>Пункт меню 2</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Что то ваш скрипт не работает

Comment: А вы пришлите ваш код в контексте html